# Serve Django project on local WiFi Network

Tags: python, django

I used

`python manage runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

to start the server so that I can access the project from other computers on my wifi network, but when i browse to internet-ipaddress:8000 on an another computer, the project doesn't load. Am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 11):

Assuming all the machines can see eachother ...

get the IP address of the machine you are running runserver on. For example run `ifconfig`  at the console.

```
ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:1e:72:b8:2a:4b  
              inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              ...
```

check if you are running a firewall. For example

```
sudo ufw status
```

if active, you need to open port 8000 so, again at the console, run

```
sudo ufw allow 8000/tcp
```

then start the runserver (or runserver_plus if using django-extensions)

```
python manage.py runserver_plus 192.168.1.2:8000
```

open a browser on another machine

```
http://192.168.1.2:8000/admin
```

Comment: you could run the code as python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 and it would still work

Comment: Ubuntu has replaced `ifconfig` with `ip a`. FYI.

Comment: Also will need to add your IP to your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

Comment: Better way to get the IP `hostname -I`

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by `internet-ipaddress`? That sounds like you're using the external IP of your router. You should be using the IP of the particular machine you're serving from, which will be an internal address like `192.168.0.2`.

Comment: Hey Daniel, that worked. But does that mean there is no way to serve a a project to someone over the internet using the django webserver?

Comment: @Ali that's a different question. To do that, you need to configure port forwarding from your router to point the particular port to your server - that's when you can use the router's external IP.

Answer (score 5):

You should bind it to your local IP address. For example

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.100:8000
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check out solutions like [Pagekite](https://pagekite.net) or <strike>[Show Off](http://showoff.io)</strike> as they're generally trivially easy to set up and offer a great deal of flexibility (and mobility) and provide a stable domain name to your localhost server.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: 192.168.2.5 is my ip. So, give your own

Open settings.py and add this to ALLOWED_HOSTS

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.2.5']
```

Then run command

> ```
> python manage.py runserver 192.168.2.5:8000
> ```

Allow access in the firewall's warning appeared.

Now access your host from the systems on same network.

Answer (score 0):

add 192.168.0.8 (or whatever your router ip is) as a string to ALLOWED_HOSTS list in settings then run server using python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.8:8000